# Strange bug in MIPS code

Tags: arrays, debugging, architecture, mips, system-calls

I am making a program for a user to input a range of numbers, and calculate the min, max and median. Right now, I am only trying to collect the numbers and echo them back to make sure I am getting them. Here is the problem:

I input numbers like this:
1
2
3
4
5

And when the array is printed out I get:
15345

It does not matter what numbers are used, the 2nd element in the array is always replace by the last element.

Here is my mips code, I know it is kind of long, but it is the shortest workable example I can make.

Note: you must enter 9999 for the program to exit the loop.

```
.data 
welcomeString:  .asciiz "Please input one number at a time, and then press enter.\n"
intArray: .word 4000
size: .word 0

.text
main:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, welcomeString
syscall
la $a0, intArray
jal gather_numbers
la $a0, intArray
jal print_array

####################################################################################

gather_numbers:
addi $sp, $sp, -12
sw $a0, 0($sp)
sw $s0, 4($sp)
sw $s1, 8($sp)
sw $t1, 12($sp)

move $s0, $a0 #the address of the array
lw $s1, size # load the size
li $t1, 0 # so it enters the loop

start_gather_numbers: beq $t1, 9999, exit_gather_numbers
              li $v0, 5 # read the integer
              syscall
              sw $v0, 0($s0)
              move $t1, $v0 # put the value into t1 to be tested
              addi $s0, $s0, 4 #increment the address
              addi $s1, $s1, 1 # increment the size
              j start_gather_numbers
exit_gather_numbers:  addi $s1, $s1, -1 # fix the size
                  sw $s1, size # store the size
              lw $a0, 0($sp) # pop the stack
              lw $s0, 4($sp)
              lw $s1, 8($sp)
              lw $t1, 12($sp)
              addi $sp, $sp, 12

####################################################################################

####################################################################################

print_array:
addi $sp, $sp, -16
sw $a0, 0($sp)
sw $s0, 4($sp)
sw $s1, 8($sp)
sw $t0, 12($sp)
sw $t1, 16($sp)

move $s0, $a0 # the address of the array
lw $s1, size # load the size of the array
li $t0, 0 # i = 0

start_print_array: bge $t0, $s1, exit_print_array
                   lw $t1, 0($s0) # load the int to print
                   li $v0, 1 # print the integer
           move $a0, $t1
           syscall
           addi $s0, $s0, 4
           addi $t0, $t0, 1
           j start_print_array
exit_print_array:  lw $a0, 0($sp)
           lw $s0, 4($sp)
           lw $s1, 8($sp)
           lw $t0, 12($sp)
           lw $t1, 16($sp)
           addi $sp, $sp, 16
```

Comment: Doesn't work at all for me. Never terminates after single enter.

Comment: Sorry, I should add that you have to enter 9999 for the loop to exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things going wrong here.

Firstly all of your functions are missing the terminating `jr $ra`.

Also, your stack manipulation is wrong. You are consistently allocating 4 less bytes than you use. If you want to put 5 words on the stack you should expand the stack by `20` not `16`.

Most importantly though here is your `intArray` directive. You have used `.word 4000` I'm guessing to allocate an array of ints, but rather you have allocated space for 1 word with the value `4000`.

To instead allocate an array of 1000 ints you could use `.space 4000` or equally `.word 0:1000`.

When I made these changes your program began to function as desired.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was a big help.